# How does Google judge page performance if audience is from one specific region & server is also in same region

Tags: html, search-engine, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I want to know how does Google Judge page performance, let us our server are located in India as our audience is from India and page speed over all is fine based on FF developer tools & Chrome ..

```
Total 68 Request
2.80 MB/2.38MB transferred
Fisnish4.62s
DOMContentLoaded:2032s
Load 2.80s

Total Request 94 (including external request)
```

and page performance goes down when we access website from EU, US etc... Which location does Google take into consideration for page performance as there are lot of article on Internet where its is mentioned page performance is important for search engine and page speed should load under 3 seconds for better ranking etc..

Since i dont know from where Google will index or crawl our website pages which can effect page performance, can anyone shed some light on this